# Processing Language: Any way to slow down for-loop execution?

Tags: for-loop, processing

I'm just learning to code, working gradually through my first coding book ever on the Processing language.  Here's an example from the book that I would like to analyze some more:

```
size(480, 120);
background(0);
smooth();
noStroke();

    for (int y = 0; y <= height; y += 40) {
        for (int x = 0; x <= width; x += 40) {
          fill(255, 140);
          ellipse(x, y, 40, 40);
    }
}
```

I'd like to know if there is any way to slow down the for-loop execution into steps so that I can see with my eyes as it is executed?  I believe that this would help me a lot now and in the future when it comes to analyzing loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is problematic to stop drawing of window because of [draw](https://www.processing.org/reference/draw_.html) function witch redraw scene 30-60 times per second.

So just for basic understanding `for` loop this should be enough:

```java
int num = 0;

void setup() 
{
  textSize(12);
  //increased size so you can see all numbers and circles
  size(480+100, 120+100);
  background(0);
  smooth();
  noStroke();
  //stop draw function - try to delete it :)
  noLoop();  
}

void draw() { 
 //just move so I dont have to rewrite all coordinates  
 translate(50, 50);  
 //old width and height 
  for (int y = 0; y <= 120; y += 40) {
    for (int x = 0; x <= 480; x += 40) {      
      fill(255, 140);
      ellipse(x, y, 40, 40);
      text(num, x, y);
      num++;
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: Yes, you knew what I was looking for here.  Thank you for your answer.  I was just looking for some way to visualize what steps the loop was going through and it looks like this is the closest that is possible.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the function `millis()` to create a pause in every loop iteration.
It returns the time since the program has been started in milliseconds. With a small while loop you can create loops that "idle" for a desired time.

Edit:
This should look like this:

```
idletime=millis()+1000;    //wait for 1 second
while(idletime>millis())
  {}
```

Comment: I think that this is getting closer to what I need, but adding this just left me with a white background instead of the black one that is specified in the code and nothing more:  http://pastebin.com/6vfDiY4p

Comment: Sorry, but i cannot see how adding the wait loop could change your program other than adding the waittime...
I would also not use a float, but a long type for the variable.